# AG-Grid what is the call back used when only rowData is changed

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I'm updating my rowData for the ag grid and was expecting for the onGridReady method to be called. Since the grid is already rendered and ready this is not getting called again when the only rowData has changed. Could anyone give any suggestion for this? I am using React.

Usage is as below,

```
<DataGrid id="gridtest" onGridReady={onGridReady}  onModelUpdated= 
{onModelUpdated} gridOptions={gridOptions} rowData={this.props.rowData} 
oncomponentStateChanged={componentStateChanged}    />
```

here this.props.rowData is being fetched after the based on some other button callback and using redux.

I'm using the ag grid from below URL 
https://www.ag-grid.com/

Comment: Hi Shashank, welcome to Stack Overflow. In order to be able to help you properly, can you include the code you currently have, (e.g. React component and gird code) With no code and minimal information we are not able to help. Thanks.

Comment: Also, are you using this library? [ag-Grid React Component](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/tree/master/packages/ag-grid-react)

Comment: @Roy Scheffers yes. I'm using the one mentioned by you.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I haven't worked with AG-Grid before, but going through their docs, this section will likely be applicable to you. [AG-Grid - React-Redux integration part 1 - Row Data Updates](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-redux-integration-pt1/#row-data-updates)

Comment: Ok, this just tells how it should be done.  I want some callback when the rowData changes and grid finished its rendering. there is a method OnGridReady() this gets called only first time and after subsequent changes in rowData there is no callback/